# how to know which element is selected in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I make multiple selected popover , in which user can select multiple values . I want to print the all selected value on screen or get a object in which all element which is selected by user .I will explain in other words .In my demo I have one button on screen .On  button click I open a pop over which have multiple selected element I want to get all element which is selected by user in pop up please check my demo .here is my demo

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpaejV

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicPopover) {
  $scope.data =[
    {"name":"A"},
    {"name":"B"},
    {"name":"C"},
    {"name":"D"},
    {"name":"E"}
  ]
  $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('my-popover.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });


  $scope.openPopover = function($event) {
    $scope.popover.show($event);
  };

   $scope.closePopover = function() {
    $scope.popover.hide();
  };
}
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your model adding a property:

```
$scope.data =[
    {"name":"A", checked: false},
    {"name":"B", checked: false},
    {"name":"C", checked: false},
    {"name":"D", checked: false},
    {"name":"E", checked: false}
  ];
```

Your list will have the property attached to the element (**ng-model**):

```
<li class="item item-checkbox">
     <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-click="itemChecked(item)">
     </label>
     {{item.name}}
  </li>
```

and you can listen to the changes adding a method (**itemChecked**) passing your item:

```
$scope.itemChecked = function(item)
  {
    alert(item.name);  
  }
```

and this is your modified [plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqWaMg).

if you want to limit the checks:

```
$scope.itemChecked = function(item)
{
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) {
      count += value.checked ? 1 : 0; 
    });
    if (count > 3)
    {
        item.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can we give a limit  only user select maximum 2 or 3 element .Mean if we give limit 2  .Then if user try to select third one then first one is  automatically  unselected

Answer (score 1):

See updated code here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPypNb

You need to add a "`value`" setting into your data JSON list and , on click, bind on each checkbox, bind the value to it.

**Model Updated**

```
  $scope.data =[
    {"name":"A", value:false},
    {"name":"B", value:false},
    {"name":"C", value:false},
    {"name":"D", value:false},
    {"name":"E", value:false}
  ]
```

**HTML updated**

```
<label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value">
     </label>
     {{item.name}}
```

Comment: can we give a limit  only user select maximum 2 or 3 element .Mean if we give limit 2  .Then if user try to select third one then first one is  automatically  unselected